# Basic math in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below is giving me a return of 25 with inputs of 3 & 4. Obviously it should be 7. This is a problem for school and I can't edit the first 3 lines or the last one. What am I missing here?

```
total_owls = 0
num_owls_A = input()
num_owls_B = input()
num_owls_A = int(input())
num_owls_B = int(input())
total_owls = (num_owls_A + num_owls_B)
print('Number of owls:', total_owls)
```

Comment: ``int(input())``

Answer (score 2):

`input()` returns input value as a string. So, you are basically concatenating strings not integers.

If you want to add them as numbers you need to convert them to numbers first like below

```
num_owls_A = int(input())
num_owls_B = int(input())
```

Again, this will create an error, if you input a non-numerical value, so you need to handle the exceptions in such case.